# How can I set javascript function in global?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5.3

I want to set my function in global js. So it can called from anywhere

I have function this :

```
$(function () {
    function formatCurrency(input) {
        return input.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1.");
    }
});
```

I put the function on the

> C:\xampp\htdocs\mysystem\resources\assets\js\main.js

And I add this : `<script src="{{URL::asset('/resources/assets/js/main.js')}}"></script>` on the

> C:\xampp\htdocs\mysystem\resources\views\layouts\app.blade

When executed, on the console exist error like this :

> GET http://mysystem.dev/resources/assets/js/main.js 404 (Not Found)

How can I solve it?

Comment: A 404 can only be caused by a few reasons. Typo, missing and incorrect configuration.

Comment: @Darkrum, You can provide answers in more detail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seems to be you're using `asset()` wrong.

asset refers to a file in `/public`.

You should compile/minimize your JS for production and put it somewhere in `/public`, i.e. `/public/js/my.js`

Comment: I had do it. But now the error : `Uncaught ReferenceError: formatCurrency is not defined`

Answer (score 2):

You should define you function as a method of the window object.

```
window.formatCurrency = function(input) {
    return input.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1.");
}
```

Another *more clean* way it would be to define your function as a method of an object called `Utils`, like below:

```
var Utils = (function(){
    function formatCurrency(input){
        return input.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1.");
    }
    return {
        formatCurrency: formatCurrency
    }
}());
```

Doing so, you will not pollute the global namespace. You will have only one variable defined in the global namespace called Util, which would contain an obejct with useful functions that can be used by other parts of your application. As it is you can't see the benefits of the latter approach. However you can consider how it would be if you wanted to use 3 more functions, that by their own use 2 other functions as helpers. If that was the case your return statement would also contained the 3 more functions, whereas the 2 functions I mentioned before wouldn't be epxosed at all !

Comment: Can you please share a example for declare multiple function or any tutorial link. I always searching for this.

Comment: @Christos, I try that. But there exist error : `GET http://mysystem.dev/resources/assets/js/main.js 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: @DavinderKumar This called module pattern. You could start from this link https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript.

Comment: @samueltoh Does your main.js exists under the folder js?

Comment: @Christos Thanks, for sharing the link.

Comment: @Christo, Yes. it exist

Answer (score 1):

You can define global function like this

```
window.formatCurrency = function(input){
            return input.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1.");
        }
```

and you are define function in ready function($(function)) then you must call    this in ready function also. So better define it outside of ready function or in self invoking function.

Comment: Not me. I try that. But there exist error : `GET http://mysystem.dev/resources/assets/js/main.js 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: But that is not script error. it means path is wrong. The path you are mentioning is not wrong. Cross check the path of file and check if your url is correct or not. i mean main.js file is not including in your page.

And please down vote a answer without trying is unacceptable.

Comment: but 404 error is means that path is not correct. First correct the paths then try global function.

Comment: I had fix it. But now the error : `Uncaught ReferenceError: formatCurrency is not defined`

Comment: i already mentioned that, you are defining function in $(function()), this means when dom will ready then function will define but you are calling function directly this means you calling function when even it is not defined. Place function outside of ready function or call function within ready function.